# Set specific tab as selected in IconTabBar

Tags: sapui5

My Icon Tab Bar code:

```js
new sap.m.IconTabBar("iconTabBar", {
    expandable: false,
    expanded: false,
    items: [
        new sap.m.IconTabFilter({
            text: "Orders",
            key: "All",
            icon: "sap-icon://home"
        }),
        new sap.m.IconTabFilter("iconTabFilter6", {
            text: "Open",
            key: "Open",
            icon: "sap-icon://home"
        }),
        new sap.m.IconTabFilter({
            text: "In Process",
            key: "InProcess",
            icon: "sap-icon://home"
        })
    ]
});
```

I put `expanded: false` so no tab is selected. Now how to make one specific tab selected? Say the 2nd one (`Open`).

What I tried:

```js
var open = iconTabBar.getItems()[1]; // retruning 2nd Item
open.setExpanded(true); // error: getItems(...)[1].setExpanded is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code example, you are setting the `expanded` property to the `IconTabFilter`, and not the `IconTabBar`.

Try setting `setSelectedKey` on the `IconTabBar` with the key of the desired `IconTabFilter` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
new sap.m.IconTabBar("iconTabBar", {
    selectedKey = "Open",
    items: [
        new sap.m.IconTabFilter({
            text: "Orders",
            key: "All",
            icon: "sap-icon://home"
        }),
        new sap.m.IconTabFilter("iconTabFilter6", {
            text: "Open",
            key: "Open",
            icon: "sap-icon://home"
        }),
        new sap.m.IconTabFilter({
            text: "In Process",
            key: "InProcess",
            icon: "sap-icon://home"
        })
    ]
});
```